# tar: /path/to/destination/jp: file is the archive; not dumped

Tags: linux, perl, tar

I'm developing a simple script to do a simple backup.
When i try to run it this syntax:

`nameofscript.pl <what_to_backup> <where_to_place_the_backup>`

```
backupsystem /var/log /home/osboxes/Desktop
```

i get this error:

```
tar: /home/osboxes/Desktop/ConteudosServer/backupsystem/jp: file is the archive; not dumped
```

Here is a portion of the code that matters:

```
else{
 `tar -cfjp $ARGV[1] $ARGV[0]`;
}
```

The rest of the code is working wonderfull.

PS: the code is deciding if it's a total backup or an incremental backup depending on the day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tar` command doesn't need `-` (dash) as command options.

Just use

```
tar cfjp $ARGV[1] $ARGV[0]
```